# Is there a way to store an image in an .xlam file?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently working on a userform-heavy Excel Add-In which uses an image as a UI element within the userform. I am currently storing the image binary on a network share, but I'd like to have the addin be self contained.

I know I can temporarily disable IsAddin and paste the image directly into a worksheet, but from there I'm not sure how to pull the image out of the worksheet and into the picture attribute of the image object in my form.

**Is there any way to store this image in the .xlam itself and then reference it within VBA space?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but have you considered simply assigning the picture to your image control at design time, instead of loading it at run time?  Or do you actually have more than one image that you would like to store, and from which you want to choose at run time?  If so, you can store all your images onto an ImageList control that you can place on your UserForm, along with your Image control.  (Note that the ImageList control will automatically become invisible at run time.).  Then you could load a specific image with `Me.Image.Picture = Me.ImageList.ListImages(index).Picture`.

Comment: I'm using the image control to display an image located in a network folder based on a filename in the selected cell. The image I'm trying to store in the add-in is for when the input is invalid. I could probably make it work though by loading it into a second image control and then hiding that control when the path is valid.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did.  I put the picture file in a UserForm and then called the image from the UserForm, made a temporary file in the directory, inserted the picture, then deleted the temporary file.  This has worked well for me and allowed me to insert a logo in sheets that were created from scratch.

In my subroutine I have the following code:

```
Dim UF as Object
Set UF = Application.Run("'Your Add-in Name.xlam'!GetUserForm1")
tempfile = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\mypic.bmp"
SavePicture UF.Image1.Picture, tempfile
```

In my case I am using in the PageSetup by inserting the file in the header.

```
ws1.PageSetup.LeftHeaderPicture.FileName = tempfile
```

To insert in a sheet you can use

```
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(tempfile)
```

Later in my subroutine I delete the temporary file with

```
Kill tempfile
```

This function needs to be in the module for this to work

```
Public Function GetUserForm1() as UserForm1
     Set GetUserForm1 = UserForm1
End Function
```

Comment: Hey, this is actually the reverse of what I'm looking to do. The image is going to be loaded into the userform itself, so I need a way to pull an image that's already in a worksheet into the picture property of the image object in the userform. I'll see if I can edit the question to be clearer.

Comment: The image in the UserForm is a holding place for the image.  You can pull it out using this code, then insert into another UserForm, thereby being self-contained.  The UserForm that I am pulling the picture from isn't used for anything other than storing the image, because you can't add an image on its own.